# Include files situated in another folder

Tags: php

I am creating and testing a php site in my localhost machine. The file structure is set out to be like this and besides I'm using php 5.4

- testsample (folder)

  - administrator (sub-folder)

    - admin_forms.php
  - css (sub-folder)

    - styles.css
  - page_elements (sub-folder)

    - navigation_top.php
  - index.php
  - header_css_js.php

Now the problem is, when I try to **include** or **require** the header_css_js.php file using the code

```
    <?php include_once '../header_css_js.php'; ?>
```

from the admin_forms.php file an error message is shown:

**Warning:** include_once(../header_css_js.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\installed\xampp\htdocs\customphp\Testsample\administrator\admin_front.php on line 11

Aside from this, when I try to **include** or **require** navigation_top.php in admin_forms.php file using the code

```
    <?php require_once '../page_elements/navigation_top.php'; ?>
```

I even tried

```
    <?php include_once("../page_elements/navigation_top.php");?>
```

but no luck

none of these codes work.

Please I urgently need help on these issues.

Comment: Instead of relative path you can give full path as include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'YOUR_FILE_PATH_RELATIVE_TO_SERVER_ROOT')

Comment: maybe you are confusing admin_front.php with admin_forms.php in your example?

Comment: yes you are right. I accidentally mentioned admin_front.php as admin_forms.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so if you are including a document in the **SAME folder**:

```
<?php include 'secondfile.php'; ?>
```

Or if you want to go **into** another folder:

```
<?php include 'folder/secondfile.php'; ?>
```

Or if you want to go **out** of the folder:

```
<?php include '../secondfile.php'; ?>
```

**For Example:**

So if you wanted to go from **admin_forms.php** to **navigation_top.css**, you would do the following:

```
<?php include '../page_elements/navigation_top.php'; ?>
```

OR

```
<?php include '../../testsample/page_elements/navigation_top.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Well you are right but how do I include navigation_top.php in admin_forms.php?

Comment: @user3397776 `include '../page_elements/navigation_top.php';`

Comment: @user3397776 I have also included it in the answer

Comment: This code doesn't work. Any idea why and what can be the alternative solution?

Comment: are you sure that the folder structure in your question in correct?

Comment: try using `include '../../testsample/page_elements/navigation_top.php';`

Comment: include '../testsample/page_elements/navigation_top.php'; worked

Comment: good, if this helped you would you please press the green tick next to the question to show that this is the answer you used :)